# what parent project do we need to add for spring boot controller project in multimodule app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have create one parent project which is parent
and have 3 project 
1. dao
2. service
3. controller(which is spring-boot project)
so in each project i need to add parent tag which is referring to parent,
but for controller there is already parent tag with spring-boot-starter-parent

so what should i do here to run this multimodule app?

Comment: Layered decoupling is outdated concept. Modern architectures decouple vertically (based on features) not horizontally (based on layers).

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: All your modules should point to your project parent, and your project parent can then have the Spring Boot parent as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just to solve your current problem, i would suggest you can move spring parent to  `<dependencyManagement>` tag in pom.xml. See below.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version> <!--change to wht u r using-->
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This way you can have use whatever parent project you want to use.